# Preform multiple cURL requests at once using PHP?

Tags: php

Using this code:

```
$file = file_get_contents($filename);
$trim = trim($file);
$ig = explode("\n", $trim);
$avail = array();
foreach($ig as $insta){
        $url = 'http://instagram.com/'.$insta;
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, '$browser');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 8);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        $pos = strpos($result, "<h2>Page Not Found</h2>");
        $fh = fopen('./free/'.$_GET['fn'].'.php', 'a+') or die("can't open file");
        if($pos === false){
            echo "<span class=\"bad\">".$insta." is taken!</span><br />";
       } else {
            echo "<span class=\"good\">".$insta." is available!</span><br />";
            fwrite($fh, $insta."<br />");
    }
}
```

I have a file (*eg.* usernames.txt), and it uses content from that file (*names on each line*) and checked to see if that name is used or not, in this case for instagram. However whenever I use this code for large files with a lot of names/lines, it always takes forever. I googled quickly a way to handle multiple requests and it found paraellel cURL and lots of others. I was wondering what you suggest?

Comment: I'd suggest not doing this. You're almost certainly in violation of instagram's terms of service, and no one likes people hammering on their servers for what is most likely spam-ish purposes.

Comment: Agreed.  If you were to speed this up, it would mean lots of simultaneous requests to their server, and would most likely get you blocked.

Comment: They probably limit how many connections you can have open, if you do violate this, they will ban you.

Comment: How about using multiple threads? Be careful on live servers you do not own though - this may raise some eyebrows.